# Would this be hard to do?

Tags: php

I want something like this to happen...

**A user has a text field and a button, he enters text in the field and clicks the button it will go to a URL. Once it goes to that URL it has a text field, this field would be automatically completed from what the user typed in at the start. On that URL there is also a button, that is automatically clicked once the text field has been automatically entered.
BUT the user only sees the first page where he entered text in the field and clicked the button. Everything that happens after he clicked that button he cannot see.**

Is there a particular phrase you would call this from what is happening? If so, what is it and how would I do it? This probably is hard to understand but I tried :/

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

You can try out different roles and workflows. It sounds like a simple admin or publishing tool.

Comment: @rizmah:If my answer is helpful please consider to accept it! Thank you very much!